# HTML Last div out of place

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Please look at the images below. For some reason the last div (Time section) is not aligning with the rest in IE. I just want it to align with the rest of the controls like its showing in Chrome.

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

IE9 & IE10
[image: IE]

ASP.NET

```
       <label>Rate:</label>
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlRateType" title="" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>

   </div>


   <div class="line-content">
       <label>Date:</label>
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaptureDate"></asp:DropDownList>

   </div>
   <div class="line-content" style="width:220px">
       <label>Time:</label>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHours" Text="0" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:DropDownList CssClass="small-dropdown" runat="server" ID="ddlMinutes">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="25" Text="15"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="30"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="75" Text="45"></asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.form-capture{
padding:10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.form-capture label{
width: 70px;
padding-top:5px;
display: inline-block;

vertical-align:central;

}

.form-capture div{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:10px;

}
.line-content{
display:inline;
width:262px;

}

.small-dropdown.selectboxit, .small-dropdown.selectboxit + .selectboxit-options{
 width: 20px;
 min-width:20px;    
}
.form-capture #txtHours {
 padding: 0 5px 0 0 ;
 background: #e8eaeb;
 border-top: 1px double #DDD;
 border-left: 1px double #DDD;
 border-bottom: 1px double #DDD;
 border-radius:6px 0 0 6px;
 border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
 height: 25px;
 width:40px;
 outline: none;
 text-align:right;
 margin-left:4px
 }
 .form-capture #txtComment {
 padding: 0 0 0 5px;
 background: #FFF;
 border-top: 1px double #DDD;
 border-left: 1px double #DDD;
 border-bottom: 1px double #DDD;
 border-radius:6px;
 border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
 height: 25px;
 outline: none;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe resolve your problem :

```
.line-content{
   display:inline-block;
   line-height : 24px; /*for example*/
   width:262px;
}
```

Else, maybe check padding because EI don't display the same sizes.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the textbox has another line-height as the dropdrowns

try giving all your divs containing the form elements a fixed line-height matching the one of your last div with the textbox!

Answer (score 0):

Create (or maybe you already have) a container div around the form.

Since you use `display: inline-block`, add a `vertical-align: top` to the container div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    /* css for above IE 8 */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Write styles for IE above version 8. You can add as many styles you want which will not affect look and feel in other browsers.